# Call functionality Popup Displaying Twice in iOS6 - PhoneGap

Tags: iphone, cordova, popup, ios6, call

We were using `<a href="tel:xxxxxxx"> Call Phone</a>` scheme for implementing **click to call function** in a **phonegap** iOS application(*version 1.8.1*).

This works fine in **iOS5 and below** but unfortunately, in **iOS6** its showing **two** popup asking *whether to call to that number or not* . Why this is happening and what we can do about this?

Any alternative code block for *click to call function* instead of mine ?

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't test on PhoneGap, but uploaded a simple HTML file up and hit it with my iPhone. I was not able to confirm this. Are you sure you don't have anything else that could be doing this? If you try a PG app with _nothing_ at all but the link, does it still happen? (So no CSS, no JS, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked fine in all iOS devices

```
document.location.href = 'tel:+1-xxxxxxx';
```